# How to debug a keyboard's keys matrix row and column and microcontroller?

Tags: drivers, keyboard, keyboard-layout, debug, hardware-detection

I was wondering how you can find the "address" of a key on a keyboard, that usually gets sent to a microcontroller on the motherboard, probably.

As example, these addresses can be called "A0, A1, A2, A3..." and so on.

Also, since there are external keyboards, is the chip controller in the keyboard or only at the motherboard? Because if it would only be on the motherboard, wouldn't it mean that the "addresses" have to be the same? Or is the microcontroller supported by a driver, that tells which key should be generated when that address has been pressed?

Comment: A key sends a code. The code is a standard, interpreted as such by the receiver, ie computer. A key combo sends not only the code of each key pressed, but also a composite code. What will mess you up is that a key with Fn also pressed doesn't send the individual codes, only the result.

Comment: The standardized  code so the keycode, is like 1,2,3,4 so the end result right? Is that also defined by an IEEE if it's standardized?

Comment: There will be developer tools available for your platform. On Mac, it's available in Xcode, or separate 3rd party apps.

Comment: Is there a problem you are trying to solve? It sounds more like electrical engineering question

Comment: well I was trying to debug the circuit so I can press a broken key without pressing the actual one

Comment: The only way you're going to get the microprocessor to send a specific code is to close the contact on that key.